# JavaScript setTimeout in a For loop issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

My issue is I am trying to increment the timeout time by the iteration value and time it by 1000. for example if the increment value is 5 it will be 5*1000 on the timeout.

I have tried various ways the first being ->

```
var textValue = 10;
function doSetTimeout(i) {
   setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, i * 1000);
}

for(var i = 1; i <= textValue; i++){
     doSetTimeout(i); 
 }
```

I also tried this ->

```
var textValue = 10;
 for(var i = 1; i <= textValue; i++){
     (function () {
         var j = i;         
         setTimeout(function timer() {
               console.log(j);
              },j*1000);
      })();     
 }
```

All I get on both is that the timeout is always set to 1000 ms even though the variable is being set correctly each time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154129/javascript-settimeout-loops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, setTimeout loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154129/javascript-settimeout-loops)

Comment: So is the idea that starting at time 0, you want the event to fire at times 1000, 3000, 6000, 10000, 15000, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout is actually the correct duration, they are just all starting at the same time because `setTimeout` doesn't stop the execution of the for loop.

This should be what you want:

```js
var textValue = 10;
delayLoop(textValue);

function delayLoop(to, at) {
    var at = at || 1;
    if (at <= to) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(at);
            delayLoop(to, at + 1);
        }, 1000 * at);
    }
}
```

Comment: They're starting at the same time, but the timeout value is `i * 1000`, so shouldn't they fire one second apart?

Answer (score 1):

You create a bunch of `setTimeout`s to be triggered after 1000ms, 2000ms, 3000ms, etc. The problem is that you create them all at the same time, so each timeout will come 1 second after the next. There's two ways to solve the problem.

1. Calculate the correct delay initially for every `setTimeout`.

The first one should be 1000ms. The second should be after 1000ms + 2000ms. The third should be after 1000 + 2000 + 3000. etc.

```
var timeoutSum = 0;
for (var i = 1000; i <= 10000; i += 1000) {
    timeoutSum += i;

    setTimeout(function() { console.log("hi!"); }, timeoutSum);
}
```

2. Don't trigger the next timeout until you've finished the current one.

We create a function to add a new timeout, and then call it from the function that gets called when the timeout ends. You can think of it as a weird inverted for loop, with the initial value outside and the condition in the middle.

```
var wait = 1000;

function addTimeout(wait) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('hi'); 

        if (wait < 10000) {
            addTimeout(wait + 1000);
        }
    }, wait);
}

addTimeout(wait);
```