# how to make loop of setTimeout in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to make an infinite loop to be able to update my chart with data posted below. I have three `setTimeout()`'s but how do I place them in a loop? Maybe some different solution is better?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    addData(myChart, [45, 50, 30, 34, 61, 53, 42], 0, );
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
    addData(myChart, [50, 40, 20, 15, 89, 63, 5], 0, );
}, 7000);

setTimeout(function() {
    addData(myChart, [45, 50, 30, 34, 61, 53, 42], 0, );
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Use `setInterval`.

Comment: @AndrewLi, for three timeouts with different intervals?

Comment: @NinaScholz OP says they want an infinite loop?

Comment: what is the source of your data?

Comment: @AndrewLi could you post a working sample with setInteravl all my attempts to make it was a faliure. Yes infinite, but can be set time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, setTimeout loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154129/javascript-settimeout-loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` instead, the function passed in will get executed every `n` ms (here 2000 for 2 seconds). And initialize `myArray` with first data point.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  addData(myChart, myArray, 0, );
  myArray = updateData(); // this will populate your array with new data after every 2 seconds.
}, 2000);

function updateData() {
  return updatedArray; // array with new data points
}
```