# For loop pauses, but prints out the Array all at once

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble Grok'ing a simple JavaScript for loop.

Here is an example:

```js
var arr = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
  setDelay(i);
}

function setDelay(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    for(const value of arr) {
    document.write(value);
    document.write("<br />");
    }
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is pause after it prints the first value, but instead it runs the entire For loop then pauses. I think I'm trying to do something with for loops that just won't work, but I would like to know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/tnmFrIRTDJI8T294Qh4z?p=preview

The example [Javascript, setTimeout loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154129/javascript-settimeout-loops) didn't help me figure it out. I still got the concept wrong as George Pantazes points out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, setTimeout loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154129/javascript-settimeout-loops)

Comment: By running your code, you can see that you are printing the entire array within the `setTimeout`. Instead of looping through the entire `arr` in the `setTimeout` `for` loop, if you access your array like `arr[i]` and only print one item instead of all of them, your code would work as you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside setTimeout - instead of printing entire array just print current element.

```js
var arr = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
for (let i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
  setDelay(i);
}

function setDelay(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(arr[i-1])
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using 1-i? Is it better to start with i = 1? I do understand that the array index starts at 0. Oh wait, so the array is four long, so you changed the i to equal 1 match the offset? Would it be better if I did i < arr.length? -Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct because you have 4 array elements and array index starts from 0

Comment: Its better to do i< arr.length. Also, its always preferable to start i with 0 rather than 1

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple issues within your code:

1. Be sure to mind that Javascript arrays are 0-based. You were starting at 1.
2. Similarly, be sure to mind the ending bound of the index (in your for loop). It was going too far even for a 1-base (it was going to 5 out of 4 available items)
3. Within the `setTimeout`, you were printing the entire array by using `for(const value of arr)`. You were probably trying to pass in `i` as an index to index only one element.

With those comments in mind, here is the working code with those parts changed:

```js
var arr = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  setDelay(i);
}

function setDelay(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(arr[i]);
    document.write("<br />");
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Refer to @Nitish-Narang's answer for better Javascript code style, although I think my advice about the indices is worth taking as well.

Comment: wow thanks. I tried to do that by setting i = to the array (out of desperation), but this makes a lot more sense. I have access to the array and i. So that would let me use arr[i].

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to creating a delay by using `setTimeout` in a loop is the `setInterval` function. `setInterval` will execute the function argument each time a specified duration of of milliseconds passes:

```js
var arr = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var i = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(logNext, 1000);

function logNext() {
  if (i < arr.length) {
    console.log(arr[i++]);
  } else {
    console.log('End of array reached!');
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}
```