# Loop object method

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, methods

i'm trying to call an objects methods at the same time with a loop.
I would create a game with a group of enemies that are move at the same time.

I create an object "Warrior"

```
    function Warrior(x, y) {

    // Coordinates x, y 

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.character = $('<div class="enemy"></div>');

    // Inserting the div inside #map
    this.character.appendTo('#map'); 


    // assigning x and y parameters

    this.character.css({        

        marginLeft: x + 'px',
        marginTop: y + 'px'

    });

    // walk method that move the div

    this.walk = function() {

        // Moving div 10px to the right
        this.character.css('left', "+=10");

    }

    }

    var enemies = new Array();
    enemies[0] = new Warrior(0, 0);
    enemies[1] = new Warrior(10, 20);
    enemies[2] = new Warrior(60, 80);

    for(var i=0;i<enemies.length;i++) {
        setInterval(function(){enemies[i].walk()}, 1000);
    }
```

I've created an array "enemies"

and I tried to call walk() methods at the same time

But nothing it happens. I would like that the divs are moving at the same time!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested `walk()` on any enemy, does it move? If it doesn't, then the problem is not in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749090/setinterval-within-for-in-loop) question

You might want to pass a parameter by value to `setInterval`:

```
for(var i=0;i<enemies.length;i++) {
    setInterval(
        function(index){   //<-- accept parameter here
            enemies[index].walk();
        }, 1000, i);       //<-- pass i here
}
```

If you do not pass the parameter, `x` variable changes while loop is running, thus all the functions will be called having `x = 2` (because you have 3 elements in your array)

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems where:

1. CSS does not allow programmatic modification in the way that javascript does. You *modify* values in javascript, and then *set* them in CSS:

   ```
   this.walk = function() {
       var current = parseInt(this.character.css('left')),
           stepped = current + 10;
       this.character.css('left', stepped);
   }
   ```
2. Your loop creates a closure on `var i` which is only declared once, so the same value will be shared across the functions. You can either have the function take a parameter, and provide it in the `setInterval` call:

   - `setInterval(function(index) { /* ... */}, 1000, i);`

   or you can put the loop within the interval function:

   ```
   setInterval(function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
            enemies[i].walk();
       }
   });
   ```

You might also want to reconsider whether your `walk` function should modify the CSS directly. You've already forgotten about your `x` and `y` coordinate attributes in this code. Perhaps you should have a `walk` method that modifies these coordinates, and a `draw` function that updates the sprites' positions based on their current coordinates.