# Strange logic with setInterval()

Tags: javascript

I'm new to learning javascript and getting strange behaviour that I don't understand

So this is printing exactly what I expect. 0,1,2,3,4

```
var numberOfPlayers = 5;
for ( i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++ ) {
    alert(i);
}
```

But when I try the following code where I want to run a function every 1 seconds I get, 5,5,5,5,5

```
var numberOfPlayers = 5;
for ( i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++ ) {
    setInterval(function () {
        alert(i);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what is actually happening here. I would expect the same numbers in both parts of code.

Comment: It actually alerts "5 ... 5 ... 5 ... 5 ..."

Comment: Are you sure that you get 5, 6, 7, 8, 9... and not only 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setInterval() within for .. in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749090/setinterval-within-for-in-loop)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Comment: Yep Sorry pointy your right. It's something i had early that did the other. I'll correct the question.

Comment: change it to `var i = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The I is not bound in the inner function inside the loop -- to something like this to bind it in each iteration of the loop

```
var numberOfPlayers = 5;
for ( i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++ ) {
   (function(i) { 
      setInterval(function () {
          alert(i);
      }, 1000);
   })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first instance, you alert the value of `i` as it goes around the loop.

In the second, you alert the value of `i` after one second. By the time that second has passed, the loop has finished going around five times, so the value of `i` at the time is the last value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting 5 5 5 5 5. The reason is that your for loop very quickly runs and binds the function to run 5 times.  It iterates through itself until i is equal to 5.  By the time the second is up and the function is scheduled to run, i is equal to 5.  It will then repeat every 1 second 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin explained in his answer, it's an issue of timing and because of the closure inside of `setInterval()`. There's a good explanation here: [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue).

For a case like this I would probably use the code @Soren suggested. Another option would be to use a separate function:

```
var numberOfPlayers = 5;
for ( i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++ ) {
    intervalAlert(i);
}

function intervalAlert(i) {
    setInterval(function () {
        alert(i);
    }, 1000);
}
```

See also http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/03/javascript-node-js-and-for-loops/