# How to delay each iteration of a each loop inside a {{#each}} with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, each

I'm looping over each values of an array to create Highcharts graphs on the client webpage. The problem is that it lags a bit because it do the each iteration a little too fast.

So my idea is to do something like this:

```
 {{#each containersToCreateChart}}  
 some html that I need to do for each one  
 then wait X milliseconds
 and do the next iteration
 {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `meteor`. But if I want to achieve what you are trying to do in `Javascript` I will do like this.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(i) {

    setTimeout(function() {

      console.log('delayed by 2 seconds, now value of "i" is:' + i);
    }, 2000);
  })(i);
}
```

for more you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749090/how-to-use-setinterval-function-within-for-loop)

Comment: Yes for sure in Javascript it's pretty easy but I try to perform that in the HTML each loop of Meteor. I got an idea with your answer I'll try something and give you a feedback

Comment: So no my idea didn't work, (it was to add every X millisecond values inside the array who is the one where the each works) but I can't. So your answer is not the right one but thank you for the help