# I can't get the setInterval function to work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simon says game and i need the background to change randomly every second. It changes, but the it does everything at once. I'm planning on adding a stylesheet later on, but for now, I just need this to work. Please help. I'm a beginner, so please be gentle.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simon Says</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="blue()" class="blue">Blue</button> 
        <button onclick="green()" class="green">Green</button>
        <button onclick="red()" class="red">Red</button>        
        <button onclick="yellow()" class="yellow">Yellow</button>
        <button onclick="ready()" class="ready">Ready</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var seq = [0,1,2,1,3,2];
var rnd; 

function ready(){
    rnd = seq.length + 1;
    for(i = 0; i <= rnd;){
        seq[rnd] = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        setInterval(
        function () {
            switch(seq[i]){
                case 0:
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,255)";
                break;

                case 1:
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,255,0)";
                break;

                case 2:
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,0,0)";
                break;

                case 3:
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,0)";
                break;
            }
        }, 1000);
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    }
    rnd++;
}
```

Comment: You define `ready()` but never call it

Comment: ``ready()`` is called ``onclick``.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749109/4803039 I believe it answers your question

Comment: why are you calling setIntervals inside a for? After 1000ms, 6 setIntervals will be triggered, changing your color for same ones once `i` is stored in setInterval function scope...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use setInterval function within for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749090/how-to-use-setinterval-function-within-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is not really what you want here. Try an alternative approach -

```js
const buttons =
  { red: document.querySelector('.red')
  , green: document.querySelector('.green')
  , blue: document.querySelector('.blue')
  , yellow: document.querySelector('.yellow')
  }
  
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms))

const playSequence = async (seq, speed = 500) =>
{ for (const s of seq)
  { buttons[s].classList.toggle('lit', true)  
    await sleep (speed)
    buttons[s].classList.toggle('lit', false)
    await sleep (speed)
  }
}

playSequence ([ 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red' ])
  .then(_ => console.log('done'))
```

```css
.red { --rgb: 255, 0, 0; }
.green { --rgb: 0, 255, 0; }
.blue { --rgb: 0, 0, 255; }
.yellow { --rgb: 255, 255, 0; }


button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: rgba(var(--rgb), 0.25);
}

button.lit {
  background-color: rgba(var(--rgb), 1);
}
```

```html
<button class="red"></button>
<button class="green"></button>
<button class="blue"></button>
<button class="yellow"></button>
```

Adjust the `speed` to increase difficulty -

```
// 200 ms delay
playSequence ([ 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red' ], 200)
  .then(_ => console.log('done'))
```

Expand the snippet below to see it play faster -

```js
const buttons =
  { red: document.querySelector('.red')
  , green: document.querySelector('.green')
  , blue: document.querySelector('.blue')
  , yellow: document.querySelector('.yellow')
  }
  
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms))

const playSequence = async (seq, speed = 500) =>
{ for (const s of seq)
  { buttons[s].classList.toggle('lit', true)  
    await sleep (speed)
    buttons[s].classList.toggle('lit', false)
    await sleep (speed)
  }
}

// 200 ms delay
playSequence ([ 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red' ], 200)
  .then(_ => console.log('done'))
```

```css
.red { --rgb: 255, 0, 0; }
.green { --rgb: 0, 255, 0; }
.blue { --rgb: 0, 0, 255; }
.yellow { --rgb: 255, 255, 0; }


button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: rgba(var(--rgb), 0.25);
}

button.lit {
  background-color: rgba(var(--rgb), 1);
}
```

```html
<button class="red"></button>
<button class="green"></button>
<button class="blue"></button>
<button class="yellow"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more DRY, and resolve the loop/timer issue, by simply adding the colours to an array and setting the body background to the index of that array given by the random index. Instead of `setInterval` I've used `setTimeout` which calls a function until the number of steps has been completed.

```js
// Cache the DOM elements
const out = document.querySelector('#out');
const { body } = document;

const seq = [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2];

// Set up your color array
const cols = ["rgb(0,0,255)", "rgb(0,255,0)", "rgb(255,0,0)", "rgb(255,255,0)"];

function ready() {

  // `next` accepts a parameter c which is the current
  // step count. It's default is 0
  const next = function(c = 0) {

    // If the step count is less than 6
    if (c < 6) {

      // Update the DOM...
      out.textContent = `Step: ${c + 1}`;
      body.style.backgroundColor = cols[seq[c]];

      // ...and call the function again after a second
      // incrementing the step count
      setTimeout(next, 1000, ++c);
    }
  }

  // Call the loop the first time
  next();
}
```

```css
#out { background-color: white };
```

```html
<button onclick="ready()" class="ready">Ready</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```