# Ajax + jQuery code starts spamming requests after a couple of seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to change the content of a div of the page every 5 seconds. I've realised that it creates a loop that sends more requests every time. It changes the page content but spams requests.

I don't know how to fix it without breaking it even more.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  sendRequest();

  function sendRequest() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "chat.txt",
      success: function(data) {
        $('.chat').html(data);
      },
      complete: function() {
        setInterval(sendRequest, 5000);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: For every iteration of your loop you're creating *another* interval, which means N+1 requests will be sent. As you're recursively calling `sendRequest`, use `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`

Comment: See [this specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749109/519413) in the duplicate I've marked